# SQL group by with replacing different values

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Is this possible to group data but replace the different values as(for example) `@` using PostgreSQL. Or better and more productive will do it with JAVA?

there is some table with the next data

```
 id  name1  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
  1   lol    0   1   1    0   0
  2   lol    0   1   1    0   0
  3   lol    0   1   1    0   0
  4   kek    1   1   1    1   0
  5   kek    2   1   1    0   0
  6   kek    4   1   1    0   0
  7   kek    3   1   1    0   0
```

and I need to retrieve name with the grouped identical data, but different data must view as `some char`
For example:

```
  name1  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
  lol    0   1   1   0   0
  kek    @   1   1   @   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5a80c78fc16155d983556ce85fccd548)

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT f1) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE MAX(f1)::text END as f1,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT f2) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE MAX(f2)::text END as f2,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT f3) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE MAX(f3)::text END as f3,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT f4) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE MAX(f4)::text END as f4,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT f5) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE MAX(f5)::text END as f5
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY name
```

For every column:

1. Group by name
2. Aggregate `COUNT(DISTINCT)` counts the distinct values
3. All aggregates where the count gives more than one distinct value results in your new character
4. Other give out the one single value. (Because you need an aggregate functions caused by the `GROUP BY`. The most simple way is taking `MAX` or `MIN`, it doesn't matter - there's only one value). Because of adding a value of `text` type, all other values have to be casted into the same column type since it is not allowed to get more types in one column. So if you really have `integer` values it would be better to take an `integer` value for your "marking" values as well. Maybe a negative could do it, if you don't have any negative values or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use case when with a subquery.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  name1 varchar(50),
    f1 int,
   f2  int,
  f3 int, 
  f4 int,
  f5 int
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('lol',0,1,1,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('lol',0,1,1,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('lol',0,1,1,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('kek',1,1,1,1,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('kek',2,1,1,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('kek',4,1,1,0,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('kek',3,1,1,0,0);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT distinct
name1,
CASE WHEN  
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f1) cnt
  FROM T tt 
  WHERE t1.name1 = tt.name1) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE t1.f1::VARCHAR(50) END,
  CASE WHEN  
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f2) cnt
  FROM T tt 
  WHERE t1.name1 = tt.name1) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE t1.f2::VARCHAR(50) END,
  CASE WHEN  
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f3) cnt
  FROM T tt 
  WHERE t1.name1 = tt.name1) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE t1.f3::VARCHAR(50) END,
  CASE WHEN  
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f4) cnt
  FROM T tt 
  WHERE t1.name1 = tt.name1) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE t1.f4::VARCHAR(50) END,
    CASE WHEN  
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f5) cnt
  FROM T tt 
  WHERE t1.name1 = tt.name1) > 1 THEN '@' ELSE t1.f5::VARCHAR(50) END  
FROM T t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6ba53/20/0)**:

```
| name1 | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5 |
|-------|----|----|----|----|----|
|   kek |  @ |  1 |  1 |  @ |  0 |
|   lol |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

No subquery is necessary here. You can do it in a single query with `GROUP`. Take a look:

```
SELECT
  name1,
  CASE WHEN array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT f1), 1) = 1 THEN min(f1)::text ELSE '@' END AS f1,
  CASE WHEN array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT f2), 1) = 1 THEN min(f2)::text ELSE '@' END AS f2,
  CASE WHEN array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT f3), 1) = 1 THEN min(f3)::text ELSE '@' END AS f3,
  CASE WHEN array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT f4), 1) = 1 THEN min(f4)::text ELSE '@' END AS f4,
  CASE WHEN array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT f5), 1) = 1 THEN min(f5)::text ELSE '@' END AS f5
FROM T
GROUP BY name1;
```

What's going on here:

1. Rows are grouped by `name1`
2. For each group, `array_agg` function returns an array of attributes of a given field
3. Duplicates in that array are removed by `DISTINCT` clause
4. `array_length` function returns the number of elements in the array. Since array has no duplicates, it is the number of unique elements.
5. With `CASE` statement the result is formatted. If an array has 1 element then it is shown (converted to text). Otherwise `@` is shown.

Sandbox: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3vxfeU8SzRRhtCcTvzj9fG/0

Comment: Why so complicated? Instead of `array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT f1), 1)` you could use `COUNT(DISTINCT f1)` -- have a look at my answer

Comment: @S-Man yup, your solution is more elegant